# Ruby floor gives incorrect decimal points

Tags: ruby

Running into some weird outputs using floor with params for decimal places.

```
100.1111.floor(1)
=> 100.1
100.1111.floor(2)
=> 100.11
100.1111.floor(3)
=> 100.111
100.1111.floor(4)
=> 100.111 # why is this even the correct answer
100.1111.floor(5)
=> 100.1111
```

Why would the `floor(4)` only give 3 decimal places back and why would `floor(5)` give the correct response?

I attempted to see if this was an error so I tried a different float.

```
100.111111.floor(1)
=> 100.1
100.111111.floor(2)
=> 100.11
100.111111.floor(3)
=> 100.111
100.111111.floor(4)
=> 100.1111
100.111111.floor(5)
=> 100.11111
100.111111.floor(6)
=> 100.111111
```

But it seems that this isnt the case because `floor` works correctly for other float numbers. I tried with `100.111` and other floats and they all seem to work. Only `100.1111` seems to be giving the issue. Is this a problem with the implementation of `Float#floor`?

Ruby version is `ruby 3.0.3p157` if that helps.

Comment: Do some searching, and you’ll see that the concept of float precision is pretty basic stuff (as in fundamental, not as in simple) and his been covered ad nauseam.  As such, I think this question should be closed.  Having said that, here’s a good place to start a little reading:  https://www.rubyguides.com/2016/07/numbers-in-ruby/

Comment: The _exact_ decimal value for `100.1111` as a 64-bit binary float is `100.111099999999993315213941968977451324462890625`. Maybe that gives some insights.

Comment: @Stefan perfect explanation thank you

Comment: @MichaelB that was not helpful even after reading through it and scouring through the answers about floating point inaccuracies on StackOverflow. It mentioned nothing of declaring a value as being inaccurate (ie `a = 0.1`); only mentioned how the math from two floating points are inaccurate.

Comment: Read it again.  Its pretty clearly spelled out that  the floating point numbers themselves are imprecise.  Also, I think you may have missed the fact that you ARE performing calculations in your example.  You can't complete the rounding operation without doing some math.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Float point numbers can not represent every number/precision, I suggest you to try the most famous example `0.1 + 0.2` that fails to represent `0.3` in most languages.

If you really care about precision in ruby use BigDecimal

```
require 'bigdecimal/util'

puts BigDecimal('100.1111').floor(1).to_digits
puts BigDecimal('100.1111').floor(2).to_digits
puts BigDecimal('100.1111').floor(3).to_digits
puts BigDecimal('100.1111').floor(4).to_digits
puts BigDecimal('100.1111').floor(5).to_digits
puts BigDecimal('100.1111').floor(6).to_digits
```

https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html

Comment: In my case, in Rails 7, this works perfectly. Thanks.